# Why does a heartbeat take O(log N) time to propagate

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed, distributed-system, gossip

I was reading about gossip style failure detection.

In the notes that I was reading it's stated that: `a single heartbeat takes O(log(N)) time to propagate` but this statement is not explained

Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 2):

Because the most effective way of propagation in such case is using the Binary Tree structure (or any k-ary tree). First node sends message to its children, they send message to their children etc. Binary tree has height of `log n`, every level in the tree represents one stage of propagating messages, so the overall time equals `O(log n)`.

Answer (score 1):

You start by sending message to k nodes. Each of them sends a message to k nodes and collects back their responses.  Each hop multiplies the number of nodes that have received the message by k. All the nodes have received the message when k^t >= N.  The clock time it takes for this to happen is proportional to t, the number of hops.

k^t = N => log_k(N)=t

We know that the clock time is proportional to t, so it must be proportional to log_k(N).

I'm not familiar with gossip in particular but this answer applies to most broadcast messages on most cluster fabrics.